# Remove string from val();

Tags: jquery

My input looks like this :

```
<input id="edit-recipient" name="recipient" value="Pixelwarrior [user]" type="text">
```

I want to remove [user] from value attribute. I began with this code in jquery :

```
var attr_input = $('#edit_recipient').val();
attr_input_destinataire.replace('[user]','');
```

It does not work.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: You aren't assigning it back to the value. You are just replacing it in the variable. Not to mention that your second variable is probably undefined unless its a typo?

Comment: `$('.#edit_recipient')` should be `$('#edit-recipient')` remove the leading dot. Also, you need to re-assign the value. Strings are immutable.

Comment: My first question would be why do you have bad data in  your HTML to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So.. you need to change a couple of things. Firstly `$('#edit_recipient').val();` should be `$('#edit-recipient').val();` as your inputs ID is `edit-recipient`. Secondly, you need to reassign the changed variable string to your input value. You could do it like this:

```
$('#edit-recipient').val($('#edit-recipient').val().replace(' [user]', ''));
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjnsdwr2/)

or as zzzzBov suggests:

```
$('#edit-recipient').val(function() { 
  return $(this).val().replace(' [user]', '');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjnsdwr2/1/)

Comment: `.val()` can take a function which is more concise